# Remove white space from a pgfplots plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to make a bar plot in pgfplots that consists of just a single bar. I managed to do this but, as can be seen in the picture below, there is a lot of white space left and right of the bar. I would like to remove this space or ideally have a way to precisely control how much space there is. I am currently using the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar stacked, ymin=0,  
        bar width=1cm,
        nodes near coords, 
        % remove white space above bar
        enlargelimits=false,
        %hide all unecassary elements
        %axis line style={draw=none},
        tick style={draw=none},
        yticklabels={,,},
        xticklabels={,,},
        ]
        \addplot [fill=blue] coordinates {
            (0,15)};
        \addplot [fill=red] coordinates {
            (0,60)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I tried changing the width of the plot but setting this to 2cm gave me a "dimensions too large" error even though the bar is just 1cm wide. I also experimented with setting xmin and xmax, but I only managed to make the bar take up more of the chart instead of making the chart smaller. Does anyone have a suggestion what I can do?
[image: Current Plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need `pgfplots` for a single bar bar plot?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum width=1cm, minimum height=15mm, fill=blue, draw, outer sep=0pt] (15) {15};
\node[minimum width=1cm, minimum height=60mm, fill=red, draw, outer sep=0pt, above = -\pgflinewidth of 15] (60) {60};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great. Could you elaborate a bit on the part of the code that makes the numbers appear in the bar, in particular how the positioning works? I would like to be able to place additional numbers / texts next to the bar, so I need to understand how this works.

Comment: node's text is by default placed at center of the node. But you can add other nodes or more text into the node. I suggest to read the documentation: https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.4